# Using tcllib's autoproxy with tls

Tags: ssl, tcl

How is tcllib's autoproxy supposed to work with tls support? I've read the documentation and taken the following minimal example from it but I just can't get it to make any https connections whatsoever:

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh
package require autoproxy
package require http
package require tls

::autoproxy::init
::http::register https 443 [list ::autoproxy::tls_socket -tls1 1]
#::http::register https 443 [list ::tls::socket -tls1 1]
set token [::http::geturl "https://example.com/" -validate 1]
puts [::http::meta $token]
::http::cleanup $token
```

which results in:

```
handshake failed: resource temporarily unavailable
    while executing
"::http::geturl "https://example.com/" -validate 1"
    invoked from within
"set token [::http::geturl "https://example.com/" -validate 1]"
    (file "./https.tcl" line 9)
```

I have no proxy servers defined via the http_proxy envvar and when using ::tls::socket directly it works fine. I'm using tcl 8.6.1, tcllib 1.15, and tls 1.6.

Comment: I use almost the same (different system, but worth a shot...):
`package require http;  
package require tls;  
package require autoproxy;
autoproxy::init;  
http::register https 443 autoproxy::tls_socket`

Comment: Changing the order like that doesn't make a difference here. Does the above script work for you? If so what OS, tcl and package versions are you using? I'm beginning to wonder whether this is a bug.

Comment: Note that I also didn't have the `-tls1 1`... I'm on windows using tcl 8.5.15, http 2.7.12, tls 1.6.3 and autoproxy 1.5.3... It did work for me (using https://google.com)

Comment: Using plain `::autoproxy::tls_socket` without a list of arguments containing `-tls1 1` and requesting `https://google.com` doesn't make a difference for me unfortunately.